# How to create a downloadable CSV file from database values with PHP in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I am trying to create a new page in the Wordpress Admin sidebar named "CSV". When you click on this page, I would like it to download a CSV file populated with values from a database table. I've created some code for this, but when the CSV file is downloaded it contains all kinds of junk HTML ... the CSV file basically contains all the HTML and stylesheet links from the Admin panel. I just want a CSV file with the database values, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here is my code:

```
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

 function my_admin_menu() {  // add a menu option to the WordPress Admin sidebar
     add_menu_page('CSV', 'CSV File', 'manage_options', 'csv-file', 'csvFile',    'dashicons-admin-post',6);
 }

 function csvFile() {
     ob_start();

     global $wpdb;


     // Set the content type to CSV
     header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');

    // Set the response header to specify that the file should be downloaded as an attachment
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=redirect_export.csv');

     $values=array();

     $values = array(
         ['source URL', 'target URL']
     );

     $table_name = 'wp_wbz404_redirects';

     $results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $table_name"); // Query to fetch data from database table and storing in $results

     if(!empty($results)){
         foreach ($results as $result){ 
             $home = home_url();
             $source_url = $result->url;
             $source_url =  $home.$source_url;
             $id = $result->final_dest;
        
             if($id == 0){
                 continue;
             }else{
                 $target_url = get_permalink( $id );
                 //build CSV
                 $redirects = array (
                     array($source_url, $target_url)
                 );
                 $values = array_merge($values,$redirects);
              }
         }
    
         $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    
         // Write the data to the file
         foreach ($values as $row) {
           fputcsv($fp, $row);
         }
    
         fclose($fp);
    
     }else{
         echo "NO RESULTS";
     }

     return ob_get_clean();
 }
```

Comment: Remove `ob_start();` and `return ob_get_clean();`, then add a *die;* after *fclose($fp);*

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue you're facing is due to some HTML being included in your CSV file. To ensure that your CSV file contains only database values, you should prevent any HTML output in your WordPress admin page. You can achieve this by using the '**ob_clean()**' function to clear any output buffers before creating the CSV file.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
function generate_csv() {
    ob_clean(); // Clear output buffer to prevent HTML from being included
    
    $results = your_function_to_fetch_database_values(); // Replace this with your database query
    
    if (!empty($results)) {
        $values = array();
        
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            // Your code to populate $values with database values here
        }
        
        header('Content-Type: text/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"');
        
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
        
        // Write the data to the file
        foreach ($values as $row) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }
        
        fclose($fp);
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "NO RESULTS";
    }
}

// Add your admin menu page hook here
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_csv_page');

function add_csv_page() {
    add_menu_page('CSV', 'CSV', 'manage_options', 'csv-page', 'generate_csv');
}
```

This code should create a downloadable CSV file with only the database values when you click on the "CSV" page in the WordPress admin sidebar. Make sure to replace '**your_function_to_fetch_database_values()**' with your actual database query to fetch the values you need.